# My python UDP sendto() is unable to send data to a "client"

Tags: python, sockets, server, tcp, udp

I am trying to write a server that listens on localhost and has both TCP and UDP ports and also sends data over TCP and UDP.
I have managed to get the data receiving part to function but cannot send data.

I tried using the UDP sendto.
This is the host and port details. The float_value and bool_value are global variables, in which received TCP data is stored.

```
class lnkserve:
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    tcp_ports = [30000, 30001, 30002]  # Port for TCP clients
    udp_ports = [12345,12346, 12347]   # Port for UDP clients
    sockets =[]
    sockets_udp =[]
    float_value = 0.0
    bool_value = False
```

The handle for TCP data is this

```
 @static method
    def handle_tcp(client):
        try:
            float_value_received = False

            while True:
                # Receive float data
                float_data = client.recv(8)
                if not float_data:
                    break
                lnkserve.float_value = struct.unpack('!d', float_data)[0]
                print("Received float via TCP:", lnkserve.float_value)
                float_value_received = True

                # Receive boolean data if float statement not activated
                if not float_value_received:
                    bool_data = client.recv(1)
                    if not bool_data:
                        break
                    lnkserve.bool_value = struct.unpack('!?', bool_data)[0]
                    print("Received boolean via TCP:", lnkserve.bool_value)

        except ConnectionResetError as c:
            print("TCP Client has left", c)
        except Exception as e:
            print("TCP Error:", e)
        finally:
            client.close()
```

The UDP method is this. Currently I am not storing data received over UDP as I want to get receive_TCP_Data - server - Send_UDP_data communication pathway working. I am sending the global (and modified by the TCP method values - float_value and bool_value)

```
@staticmethod
    def handle_udp_cl():
        try:
            while True:
                for s in lnkserve.sockets_udp:
                    data, address = s.recvfrom(1024)

                    float_bytes = struct.pack('d', lnkserve.float_value)
                    bool_bytes = struct.pack('?', lnkserve.bool_value)
                
                    s.sendto(float_bytes, address)
                    s.sendto(bool_bytes, address)

                    if data:
                    # Assuming data contains a boolean value followed by a float value
                        bool_value, float_value = data.decode().split(",")
                        bool_value = bool(int(bool_value))
                        float_value = float(float_value)

                    # Process the data as needed
                        print(f"Received via UDP from {address}: {bool_value}, {float_value}")
```

But this is not working, when a Dummy UDP "client" tries to receive data, it doesn't receive anything. There are no error messages either.
I am using VScode and I remember reading on one StackOverflow thread that some code editors cannot work with UDP data but I have not tested it yet.

Does anyone know what's going wrong, admittedly It is not the most efficient code but should work?

Comment: Is the Dummy UDP client sending anything to your server before it then tries to receive? Your server code is expecting the client to do so. Have you tried using a packet sniffer, like WireShark, to make sure your data is actually being transmitted as expected?